# How do i set "nav-item active" in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm building an application using Blazor & Bootstrap. I want to use a standard bootstrap navbar. I can't figure out how to add the "active" class to the `<li>` tag selected.

This is my code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/counter" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Counter</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/fetchdata" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Fetch data</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The built in `<NavLink>` which is a blazor component changes the class for the `<a/>` automatically. But since i am using bootstrap navbar i need to add "active" to the class of the selected `<li>`.

This is how it should look like when the link is active:

```
 <li class="nav-item active">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the navigation manager:

```
<li class="nav-item @GetActive("", NavLinkMatch.All)">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
</li>

@code {

    [Inject]
    NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => NavigationManager.LocationChanged += (s, e) => StateHasChanged();

    bool IsActive(string href, NavLinkMatch navLinkMatch = NavLinkMatch.Prefix)
    {
        var relativePath = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri).ToLower();
        return navLinkMatch == NavLinkMatch.All ? relativePath == href.ToLower() : relativePath.StartsWith(href.ToLower());
    }

    string GetActive(string href, NavLinkMatch navLinkMatch = NavLinkMatch.Prefix) => IsActive(href, navLinkMatch) ? "active" : "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a custom template to achieve this:

```
<NavLink href="/myhref">
    <Template>
        <li class="@(context.isActive ? "active" : string.Empty)">
             <a href="@context.href">@context.content</a>
        </li>
    </Template>
    My link description
</NavLink>
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5528)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I read everything on the link, however it seems like the NavLink component doesn't have support for Templates.

According to the provided link: The NavLink component has a template parameter:

[Parameter] private RenderFragment<(string href, bool isActive, RenderFragment content)> Template { get; set; } = GetDefaultTemplate();

However, i decompiled the NavLink component and it doesn't include this.

Comment: I can see that `NavLink` doesn't have a `Template` property, but it does have a `ChildContent` property of type `RenderFragment`. I haven't been able to test it myself, but maybe it will do the same, seeing as the Github issue says the `Template` property also is of type `RenderFragment`?

Comment: I tried a bit myself, but couldn't get it to work with `ChildContent`, so that's not the way to go, and I didn't see any other properties that seemed helpful. So either create your own `NavLink`, or do it as @BrianParker suggested in his answer.

Comment: For now it seems like i'll be going with BrianParker's solution. I will post here if i figure out any other way to do it. Looks like NavLink component also uses NavigationManager for comparing the URL to the href of the navlinks. Using NavigationManager is probably a best practice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bootstrap NavBar and Blazor's NavLink without having to add any additional code. The one caveat is that your "active" class will added to the `<a>` tag, as per Bootstrap's documentation, and not on the `<li>` tag.

From the Bootstrap 5.x docs (the initial example for navbar):

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
```

With that in mind, the Blazor NavLink component replaces the `<a>` tag:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        <hr />
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Reporting" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
        Reporting
        <hr />
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

Finally, once this is in place, you can add your own CSS to further modify the appearance:

```
.nav-link > hr {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: white;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-item .nav-link.active > hr {
    visibility: visible;
    filter: blur(1.5px);
}
```

No other code is needed.

In my example, a blurred line will appear under the active menu item, as seen below (note, additional HTML/CSS would be required to achieve the completed visual):

[image: Image of described technique]